# php upload with wamp server yields access denied

Tags: php, upload, wamp

I am very new to web coding (about a week or so!) but am making great strides.  I've run into a problem that I'm not sure will be a big issue or not.

I'm building a website to showcase my photography (www.MattTilghman.com --- VERY much a work in progress).  Uploading the files manually and editing all the html files accordingly will be very annoying and time consuming, so I've decided to write a PHP script which will help me streamline the process.

This PHP file has not made it online yet, I'm doing all my testing locally first.  Right now it does exactly what I'm asking it to (though it's not finished, so you might see some hanging chads in the code).

Basically right now, when I select the file names, it moves them from their original folder, to the one I specify, which is located somewhere in the wamp/www/htdocs etc.  It then edits the html files to add code which points to this image, and low and behold, the new html files do exactly as I want, and show the images fine.

HOWEVER, if I navigate to the copies of the images within the wamp server directory, they cannot be opened by any program.  I guess the html is displaying them fine, but every other program gives me an "access denied" error.  How do I avoid this?  Is there some sort of access permission I need to set in the PHP file?  Will any of this be a problem once I move the file online?

As I said, I've only been doing this about a week, so be gentle.  I'm a quick learner, but nonetheless, it would be appreciated if answers were as explicit as possible.

Thanks so much and please let me know if y'all need anything else.
Oh BTW I'm using aptana studio 3, if that matters.

code:

```
<?php 

$PicName = str_replace("-T.png","",$_FILES["fileT"]["name"]);
$PicIDL = $PicName . "-L"; //PicIDL is the ID for the "large" div
$PicTitle = $_POST["pictitle"];  //PicTitle has spaces instead of hyphens
$PicCaption = $_POST["piccaption"];
$PicKeywords = $_POST["pickeywords"];

$fileName = $_POST["location"] . "-Photos.html"; //this is the galley to edit the html of

// upload and get filename and stuff for thumbnail
$fileNameLocT = "images/" . $_POST["location"] . "/" . $_FILES["fileT"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileT"]["tmp_name"],$fileNameLocT);

// upload and get filename and stuff for large image
$fileNameLocL = "images/" . $_POST["location"] . "/" . $_FILES["fileL"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileL"]["tmp_name"],$fileNameLocL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Will any of this be a problem once I move the file online?

Best thing will be to upload it and try it.  I believe you are saying that via the web page, it displays fine but if you navigate using windows explorer, you can't view the images.

When you do put the code online, are you using a windows hosting service or a linux one - this may also cause differences once you have uploaded.

Out of interest, i also do photography as a hobby and have looked at a couple of solutions for putting my photos online.  Even though i'm in IT for a living and have done some PHP/Mysql development, i have considered a wordpress photo blog as a better alternative - have you had a look at those ?  I understand if you really want to learn how to code, then it's interesting to take the harder path but if it's just a means to an end, you might find you can get what you want.  Something like [this](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/07/wordpress-portfolio-themes.html), [this](http://designwoop.com/2012/01/25-best-wordpress-photography-themes/) or [this](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/wordpress/wp-photography-themes/) might give you some ideas.